# Increase numpy array elements using array as index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to efficiently update some elements of a numpy array A, using another array b to indicate the indexes of the elements of A to be updated. However b can contain duplicates which are ignored whereas I would like to be taken into account. I would like to avoid for looping b. To illustrate it:

```
>>> A = np.arange(10).reshape(2,5)
>>> A[0, np.array([1,1,1,2])] += 1
>>> A
array([[0, 2, 3, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

whereas I would like the output to be:

```
array([[0, 3, 3, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In your index array, column index 1 occurs 3 times. If you want the elements to be incremented as many times as the index occurs, then element [0,1] should become 1 + 3 = 4.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To correctly handle the duplicate indices, you'll need to use `np.add.at` instead of `+=`. Therefore to update the first row of `A`, the simplest way would probably be to do  the following:

```
>>> np.add.at(A[0], [1,1,1,2], 1)
>>> A
array([[0, 4, 3, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

The documents for the `ufunc.at` method can be found [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html).

Comment: Thank you. It works as expected. Thank you for the pointer, I didn't know this feature, it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use numpy.histogram to find out how many values there are at each index, then add the result to `A`:

```
A[0, :] += np.histogram(np.array([1,1,1,2]), bins=np.arange(A.shape[1]+1))[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think the accepted one is more intuitive.