# Add values in numpy array successively, without looping

Tags: python, numpy

Maybe has been asked before, but I can't find it.
Sometimes I have an index I, and I want to add successively accordingly to this index to an numpy array, from another array. For example:

```
A = np.array([1,2,3])
B = np.array([10,20,30])
I = np.array([0,1,1])
for i in range(len(I)):
    A[I[i]] += B[i]
print(A)
```

prints the expected (correct) value:

```
[11 52  3]
```

while

```
A[I] += B
print(A)
```

results in the expected (wrong) answer

```
[11 32  3].
```

Is there any way to do what I want in a vectorized way, without the loop?
If not, which is the fastest way to do this?

Comment: It would be a bit churlish to close this question as a dupe when there are two good answers below, so here are a couple of places where this question has been asked before in case they're a useful reference: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069151/increase-numpy-array-elements-using-array-as-index/34069294#34069294) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069151/increase-numpy-array-elements-using-array-as-index/34069294#34069294)

Comment: @AlexRiley Found a better dup target.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `numpy.add.at`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> B = np.array([10,20,30])
>>> I = np.array([0,1,1])
>>> 
>>> np.add.at(A, I, B)
>>> A
array([11, 52,  3])
```

Alternatively, `np.bincount`:

```
>>> A = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> B = np.array([10,20,30])
>>> I = np.array([0,1,1])
>>> 
>>> A += np.bincount(I, B, minlength=A.size).astype(int)
>>> A
array([11, 52,  3])
```

Which is faster?

Depends. In this concrete example `add.at` seems marginally faster, presumably because we need to convert types in the `bincount` solution.

If OTOH `A` and `B` were `float` dtype then `bincount` would be faster.

Comment: Why would  `bincount` be faster in the when I have float? how much faster?

Comment: @Johan As I said it depends. For some reason `bincount` returns dtype float even if the input weights are int, so we have to cast back to int to be able to add to `A` which makes it slower. If `A` and `B` are float anyway, this is not necessary. `add.at` is normally only faster if the number of things to add is quite a bit smaller than the number of elements in the destination array. With your example converted to float the difference is not large, on my computer something like 10%.

Comment: I really liked the idea with `bincount`, but in my case I actually have numpy arrays (matrices) and I would like to do the adding of columns. This seems to work with `numpy.add.at`. However this is quite slow. But for `bincount` it gives the error: `object too deep for desired array`. Do you know if there is a multidimensional version?

Comment: @Johan Not aware of one, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Johan I think one can make it work, but that should be a separate question, not hidden under all that other stuff here.

Comment: @Johan By some strange coincidence some one just asked the column-wise question. It's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49012623/7207392).

Comment: Great! thanks! I will look into that

Answer (score 9):

You need to use [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
A = np.array([1,2,3])
B = np.array([10,20,30])
I = np.array([0,1,1])

np.add.at(A, I, B)
print(A)
```

prints

```
array([11, 52, 3])
```

This is noted in the doc:

> **ufunc.at(a, indices, b=None)**
>
> Performs unbuffered in place operation on operand ‘a’ for elements specified by ‘indices’. For addition ufunc, this method is equivalent to a[indices] += b, except that results are accumulated for elements that are indexed more than once. For example, a[[0,0]] += 1 will only increment the first element once because of buffering, whereas add.at(a, [0,0], 1) will increment the first element twice.