# Numpy ":" operator broadcasting issues

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

In the following code I have written 2 methods that theoretically(in my mind) should do the same thing. Unfortunately they don't, I am unable to find out why they don't do the same thing per the numpy documentation.

```
import numpy as np


dW = np.zeros((20, 10))
y = [1 for _ in range(100)]
X =  np.ones((100, 20))

# ===================
# Method 1  (works!)
# ===================
for i in range(len(y)):
  dW[:, y[i]] -=  X[i]


# ===================
# Method 2 (does not work)
# ===================
dW[:, y] -=  X.T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated, in principle you cannot operate multiple times over the same element in a single operation, due to how buffering works in NumPy. For that purpose there is the [`at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) function, which can be used on about any standard NumPy function ([`add`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.add.html), [`subtract`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html), etc.). For your case, you can do:

```
import numpy as np

dW = np.zeros((20, 10))
y = [1 for _ in range(100)]
X =  np.ones((100, 20))
# at modifies in place dW, does not return a new array
np.subtract.at(dW, (slice(None), y), X.T)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a column-wise version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49003798/7207392) question.

The answer there can be adapted to work column-wise as follows:

Approach 1: `np.<ufunc>.at`

```
>>> np.subtract.at(dW, (slice(None), y), X.T)
```

Approach 2: `np.bincount`

```
>>> m, n = dW.shape
>>> dW -= np.bincount(np.add.outer(np.arange(m) * n, y).ravel(), (X.T).ravel(), dW.size).reshape(m, n)
```

Please note that the `bincount` based solution - even though it involves more steps - is faster by a factor of ~6.

```
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=5000)
>>>
>>> repeat('np.subtract.at(dW, (slice(None), y), X.T); np.add.at(dW, (slice(None), y), X.T)', **kwds)
[1.590626839082688, 1.5769231889862567, 1.5802007300080732]
>>> repeat('_= dW; _ -= np.bincount(np.add.outer(np.arange(m) * n, y).ravel(), (X.T).ravel(), dW.size).reshape(m, n); _ += np.bincount(np.add.outer(np.arange(m) * n, y).ravel(), (X.T).ravel(), dW.size).reshape(m, n)', **kwds)
[0.2582490430213511, 0.25572817400097847, 0.25478115503210574]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a third solution for this problem. Normal Matrix multiplication:

```
ind = np.zeros((X.shape[0],dW.shape[1]))
ind[range(X.shape[0]),y] = -1
dW = X.T.dot(ind)
```

I did some experiment using the proposed methods above on some neural network data. In my example `X.shape = (500,3073)`, `W.shape = (3073,10)` and `ind.shape = (500,10)`.

The subtract version takes about 0.2 second (slowest). The Matrix multiplication method 0.01 s (fastest). Normal loop 0.015 and then `bincount`method 0.04 s. Note that in the question `y` is vector of ones. This is not my case. The case with only ones can be solved with a simple sum.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

```
for i in range(len(y)):
  dW[:, y[i]] -=  X[i]
```

This works because you are looping through and updating value which was updated last time.

**Option 2:**

```
dW[:, [1,1,1,1,....1,1,1]] -=  [[1,1,1,1...1],
                                [1,1,1,1...1],
                                .
                                .
                                [1,1,1,1...1]]
```

It does not work because update happens to 1st index at same time in parallel not in serial way. Initially all are 0 so subtracting results in -1.